# How to use observeSingleEvent in Firebase with callback when not connected?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building iOS App using Firebase, I found that the method observeSingleEvent(with or without cancel block) in Firebase would not even fire if the app is not connected to the network and there is no cached value for the location.

I need to show messages to users when the App lose connection to internet but no need to do it if there is cached value for the location when use keepSynced to it.

How can I do if the API without an error that can detect connect or not in return? Since the document says the cancelBlock will be called if you don't have permission to access this data, but it even not callback when the App without connection.

Answer (score 1):

if  and else statetment check your problem ? If it is connected, you will be call the observeSingleEvent function

```
let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
  if snapshot.value as? Bool ?? false {
    print("Connected")
  } else {
    print("Not connected")
  }
})
```

More detail : [Detecting Connection State](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities)

Comment: Thanks Emre YILMAZ. It's great to detect connection state before calling observeSingleEvent, but what if I should let the users keep using App when there is cached value of the location instead of showing no-connection message to users every time when the connection state is false?

Comment: There can be two situation. If there is no important information, cached value show and may be "no connection internet" notification  @WillChen